# Flatsome Wordpress Theme Mobile Menu Issue

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Currently using the Flatsome Theme for Wordpress.

Brief summary:
In the mobile menu, Once opened it shows the first link being pushed to the right. In inspect element is shows that, that area is a class on it own for privacy policy page.

[Mobile Menu Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZCRj.png)

[Inspect Element on Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QU7xp.png)

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Try to add css for visibility: hidden to <a> which includes Privacy policy

Comment: Hey man, I've tried doing. And no luck.
Here's a screenshot
https://imgur.com/09WSUFV

Comment: Can you share link so i can check give you hint.

Comment: http://loottrendz.com
Sorry for late reply. Thanks